# How to access a shared SkyDrive folder from Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, file-sharing, shared-folders, onedrive

A friend shared a folder on his SkyDrive with me.  The problem is that I don't see it in my SkyDrive folder on Windows 8.1 - both Explorer and the Metro app.  I can access the shared folder on the web site and on my iOS devices, but, ironically, not on my Surface Pro 2.

I see people [complaining](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsharing/how-do-i-access-a-shared-folder-from-the-skydrive/0e784c32-9f82-41f8-bfcb-3d8e19211aaa?page=6&tm=1392228588482) about this problem in 2012 - hopefully enough time to have fixed this oversight.

So how do I access that folder from Windows?  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

From MS' current [SkyDrive for 8.1 FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/skydrive-app-faq):

> **How can I browse files shared with me and Office documents I've worked on recently?**
>
> *You can't currently do this in the SkyDrive app*, but you can by going
>   to the SkyDrive website.

The iOS devices are probably able to show it to you because they're just scraping the SkyDrive web site and re-presenting that data in their app, vs. directly interfacing as a real SkyDrive client like your Surface is using.  But that's just a guess. ;)

Comment: The iOS client is made by Microsoft so I doubt that they are scraping anything.

Comment: That's kind of weird then. ;)  regardless, as the FAQ for SkyDrive on Windows 8.1 says - it's currently a no-go from their (Windows 8.1) app.